# Where is System.Tuple in portable class libraries?

Tags: c#, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, portable-class-library

I don't know if maybe I have something installed incorrectly, but having made a C# Portable Class Library targeting `.NET for Windows Store apps, .NET Framework 4.5, Silverlight 4 and higher, Windows Phone 7 and higher`, I'm getting errors that `System.Tuple` is missing.

How could this be?

Comment: To save any potential answerers looking it up, [MSDN on tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536.aspx) says it is supported in .NET for Windows Store apps, Portable Class Library and .NET 4.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Tuple[<...>]` doesn't exist in Windows Phone 7, so you can't use it if you are targeting that platform.

I've just validated, and if you create a PCL targeting:

- .NET for Windows Store apps
- .NET Framework 4.5
- Silverlight 4 and higher

but **not** "Windows Phone 7 and higher", then it works fine and you can use `Tuple[<...>]`.

For completeness, it also doesn't exist if you include Xbox 360.

Comment: Btw, you can find this info on MSDN by going to the Silverlight version of MSDN, and looking for the phone/xbox symbols on each method: this shows whether the phone/xbox variants of Silverlight include each feature - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the info. That's incredible. I'm absolutely sick of all this fragmentation.

Answer (score 2):

The [Microsoft.Bcl](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl) NuGet package includes Tuple types for Windows Phone 7.5, and will allow you to use them in a Portable Class Library targeting WP7.5, SL4, Windows Store apps, and .NET 4 (or higher platforms).

In general,  full list of portable APIs and what platforms they are available on is here: http://sdrv.ms/OVdfNc.  However, that spreadsheet doesn't include information about what types we've added support for via external means (such as the Microsoft.Bcl package).